# Import to Photos app/MacOs is disabled/greyed-out even though the iPhone is connected

Tags: iphone, photos.app

My iphone (stephenb) is successfully connected to the Macbook pro.

[image]

I have imported into `Photos.app` from this phone a couple of dozen times already. There are a few new photos that I want to import but the buttons are grayed out:

[image]

The `Photos` app has been restarted and the iPhone as well - but the buttons are still grayed out.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my iPhone were full in some way:  after removing gobs of photos and videos it is working to sync.  I did not see/notice any indicator of the memory being full and the `Settings|General|Storage` had said 8.7GB out of 16GB before deleting anything (now says 6.6 out of 16GB).  That is strange behavior.